# Вернуть индекс элемента списка, зная часть его значения

Tags: python, list

Например, есть список:

```
['Город Москва', 'Город Киев', 'Город Харьков', 'Город Краснодар']
```

Как вернуть индекс элемента зная его значение? Например Харьков.

Comment: ну, вообще-то строки `Харьков` в приведённом списке **вообще нет** (есть `Город Харьков`), поэтому возвращать-то **вообще нечего**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
In [33]: items
Out[33]: ['Город Москва', 'Город Киев', 'Город Харьков', 'Город Краснодар']
```

решение "в лоб":

```
In [34]: [i for i,x in enumerate(items) if 'Харьков' in x][0]
Out[34]: 2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
lst = ['Город Москва', 'Город Киев', 'Город Харьков', 'Город Краснодар']
pattern = 'Харьков'

# Чтобы остановиться на первом совпадении

for i in range(len(lst)):
    if pattern in lst[i]:
        print(i)
        break

# Чтобы получить все индексы где есть паттерн

print(*[i for i in range(len(lst)) if pattern in lst[i]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже сражусь за оригинальность:

```
list = ['Город Москва', 'Город Киев', 'Город Харьков', 'Город Краснодар']

for index, elem in enumerate(list):
    if (elem.find('Харьк')!= -1):
        print(index)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list=['Город Москва', 'Город Киев', 'Город Харьков', 'Город Краснодар']
i=-1
for elem in list:
    i+=1
    if elem==('Город Харьков'):
        break
print(i)
```

Comment: Для такого подхода есть метод index: `print(list.index('Город Харьков'))`.

Answer (score 0):

Просто примените метод `index()`:

```
In[2]: lst = ['Город Москва', 'Город Киев', 'Город Харьков', 'Город Краснодар']
In[3]: lst.index('Город Харьков')
Out[3]: 2
```